# VS2010 started launching vshost process automatically

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, vshost.exe

Suddenly and for no apparent reason, my VS2010 has started launching the vshost process for my project without me even trying to start it.

It's a solution with several DLL:s, one Asp.Net project and one WinForms project named `Diamonds.WinForm`. When I set `Diamonds.WinForm` to "Set as StartUp Project" and have the option "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" checked, VS2010 will IMMEDIATELY start a `Diamonds.WinForm.vshost.exe` process. I didn't even try to start debugging or anything. If I uncheck "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" the process is killed, and if I check it again, the process starts again. That is, IMMEDIATELY when I click the checkbox, before I even save the setting.

This just started happening this morning, and to the best of my knowledge I didn't change anything on my system, in my VS2010 installation or settings, or in my project settings. I did change my code and WinForms designs.

I first noticed this because when I tried to start debugging, the prompted build failed, unable to copy `Diamonds.WinForm.exe` from the `obj\Debug` folder to the `bin\Debug` folder, because it's being used by another process (the vshost process).

Any idea what makes this happen and how I can stop it from happening?

Comment: Weird, after changing some arbitrary code, I can now build again without the failing copy to `bin\Debug`. The vshost process is still running even when the debugger is not active though.

Comment: This is entirely normal, you just never noticed it before.  You already know how to "stop it from happening", untick the option.  Which is fine, there are not a lot of practical scenarios where you actually need the hosting process.  Why it keeps a lock on a DLL is something you'll have to figure out by yourself, usually best to start by disabling anti-malware.  If it is Avast then uninstall it completely.

Comment: Good to know that vshost running is normal. The main issue was that the build failed to copy the built exe to the bin folder, only when vshost was running, never when it was not running. Why that happened, I still don't know. Anyon else? I don't think BitDefender would be the culprit. CrashPlan backup seems more likely, but then why would it keep coniciding with vshost running?